# Need Help Finding Fitting Colors For This Panel

Tags: color, gimp, palette

I've been working on a set of graphic panels and believe I've come up with a good base that fits the theme of the rest of the project they're part of, except that I'm having a very hard time coming up with a color scheme for the text in these panels. I'm not sure anything within my palette looks good on the background. I also don't know if I should attempt to try a new color because, as I mentioned earlier, these panels are part of a larger theme and this would be the only place that new color shows up.
[image: The panel I have so far]

This gradient is the best I was able to come up with but I've already had one of my friends say it's hard to read.

Any ideas on better color(s) to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onscreen readability check of colors is possible for ex. by using a Color Contrast Analyzer utility which judges the readability by following the common Web Content Accessibility Guidelines: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/

You pick from the screen the text color and the background color and see immediately how WCAG judges it.  This is one example with your colors:

[image]

The result is in accordance with the comments you have already got.

We could simply make the text lighter until the contrast is acceptable, but nothing guarantees that the look and feel of your application stay right, it's your job to fix the palette.

BTW the gradients create illusion the text is behind a curved transparent plastic or glass. That's OK if your overall design (=unknown for us) needs it. But you shouldn't sacrifice the readability.